# React-bootstrap make a panel with header and without body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

There is `<Panel>` element defined in the [react-bootstrap](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#panels) library. How can I render the panel with header and without body?

```
<Panel header="header text"></Panel>
```

and

```
<Panel header="header text" />
```

gives me just

```
<div data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.0" class="panel panel-default">
  <div data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.0.0" class="panel-heading">header text</div>
  <div data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.0.1:$0" class="panel-body"></div>
</div>
```

How can I remove unnecessary div with `panel-body` class?

Comment: No,you cannot...the react-bootstrap will add that div irrespective you define the body or not

Comment: @amit_183 how do you think, will maintainers consider PR?

Comment: or you have to remove the line no. 68  in react-bootstrap library..https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Panel.js

Comment: This will kill all tests =)

Comment: Just write it yourself without using the Panel from react-bootstrap.
Create your small component for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could just include the react-bootstrap's css file and do

```
<div className="panel-heading" > whatever you want to write</div>
```

Comment: Beware putting inside a react-bootstrap <Panel></Panel> component.

If you do, your `<div class="panel-heading"></div>` will actually end up inside your `<div class="panel-body"></div>`, which is likely not what you want!